# PHP Split backend, frontend, and APIs with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

if I wanted to have my file structure be like this in the document root `/var/www/html`

```
- [ /api ] (/api/* urls)
- [ /backend ]
- [ /frontend ]
index.php
.htaccess
```

how do I set the actual document root to /frontend again, but also allows API urls to load from the /api directory

Comment: We cannot somehow magically guess what URLs are requested for the backend or for the API. You will need to provide information about the actually requested URLs.

Comment: @arkascha Just the files linked in `/frontend`, the backend file with the same name in /backend just gets required at the start of the file. So frontend/index.php would be index.php.